# Android dalvikvm thread still suspended. Can't start debugging

Tags: android, debugging, illegalargumentexception, launching

I have the following problem. I had a stable version of my android application and started adding code. When debugging the edited version of the app it threw an illegal argument exception. So i decided to comment out all the new code, **but after that i could not launch the app**.

The logcat shows that the thread is still suspended and i tried several solutions i found like remove all breakpoints and clean the project.

Problem: I can't launch my app

**Can anyone explain why this happens and how to solve it?**

Console:

```
[2015-02-27 21:42:16 - CaveExplorer] ------------------------------
[2015-02-27 21:42:16 - CaveExplorer] Android Launch!
[2015-02-27 21:42:16 - CaveExplorer] adb is running normally.
[2015-02-27 21:42:16 - CaveExplorer] Performing com.jeroenb.caveexplorer.CaveExplorerActivity activity launch
[2015-02-27 21:42:16 - CaveExplorer] Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility. Please select a target device.
[2015-02-27 21:42:18 - CaveExplorer] Uploading CaveExplorer.apk onto device '901b509d'
[2015-02-27 21:42:19 - CaveExplorer] Installing CaveExplorer.apk...
[2015-02-27 21:42:31 - CaveExplorer] Success!
[2015-02-27 21:42:32 - CaveExplorer] Starting activity com.jeroenb.caveexplorer.CaveExplorerActivity on device 901b509d
[2015-02-27 21:42:32 - CaveExplorer] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.jeroenb.caveexplorer/.CaveExplorerActivity }
[2015-02-27 21:42:32 - CaveExplorer] Attempting to connect debugger to 'com.jeroenb.caveexplorer' on port 8600
```

Logcat:

```
02-27 21:43:00.597: D/ActivityThread(5318): handleBindApplication:com.jeroenb.caveexplorer
02-27 21:43:00.597: D/ActivityThread(5318): setTargetHeapUtilization:0.75
02-27 21:43:00.597: D/ActivityThread(5318): setTargetHeapMinFree:2097152
02-27 21:43:00.607: I/System.out(5318): Sending WAIT chunk
02-27 21:43:00.607: W/ActivityThread(5318): Application com.jeroenb.caveexplorer is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
02-27 21:43:00.617: I/dalvikvm(5318): Debugger is active
02-27 21:43:00.807: I/System.out(5318): Debugger has connected
02-27 21:43:00.807: I/System.out(5318): waiting for debugger to settle...
02-27 21:43:01.007: I/System.out(5318): waiting for debugger to settle...
02-27 21:43:01.217: I/System.out(5318): waiting for debugger to settle...
02-27 21:43:01.417: I/System.out(5318): waiting for debugger to settle...
02-27 21:43:01.617: I/System.out(5318): waiting for debugger to settle...
02-27 21:43:01.817: I/System.out(5318): waiting for debugger to settle...
02-27 21:43:02.017: I/System.out(5318): waiting for debugger to settle...
02-27 21:43:02.217: I/System.out(5318): debugger has settled (1437)
02-27 21:43:02.287: I/Adreno-EGL(5318): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LNX.LA.3.5.2.2_RB1.04.04.04.087.028_msm8974_LNX.LA.3.5.2.2_RB1__release_AU ()
02-27 21:43:02.287: I/Adreno-EGL(5318): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.00.15
02-27 21:43:02.287: I/Adreno-EGL(5318): Build Date: 07/31/14 Thu
02-27 21:43:02.287: I/Adreno-EGL(5318): Local Branch: 
02-27 21:43:02.287: I/Adreno-EGL(5318): Remote Branch: quic/LNX.LA.3.5.2.2_rb1
02-27 21:43:02.287: I/Adreno-EGL(5318): Local Patches: NONE
02-27 21:43:02.287: I/Adreno-EGL(5318): Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LNX.LA.3.5.2.2_RB1.04.04.04.087.028 +  NOTHING
02-27 21:43:02.337: D/OpenGLRenderer(5318): Enabling debug mode 0
02-27 21:43:03.547: D/dalvikvm(5318): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
```

The stack trace, i hope it helps

```
DalvikVM [localhost:8600]   
    Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception IllegalArgumentException))  
        <VM does not provide monitor information>   
        Choreographer.doCallbacks(int, long) line: 584  
        Choreographer.doFrame(long, int) line: 544  
        Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run() line: 747 
        Handler.handleCallback(Message) line: 733   
        Choreographer$FrameHandler(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 95   
        Looper.loop() line: 136 
        ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 5146    
        Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
        Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 515  
        ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 732  
        ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 566 
        NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]  
    Thread [<10> Binder_2] (Running)    
    Thread [<9> Binder_1] (Running)
```

Comment: The equivalent of reaching for a hammer might be to go into settings and force stop it or even uninstall it.  You could also try plug cycling the USB cable or killing the ADB server on your development machine.

Comment: I tried this, but it did not work. I can't even launch the app to start debugging.